# Leaflet display .mbTiles files in the map

Tags: leaflet, offline, openmaptiles, osm.pbf

I have downloaded UAE mbtiles from openmaptiles site. I need to show the map in offline for UAE.  I'm using angular 4. I have converted that mbtiles into png image using mbutil. But it shows the image was damaged.

Also converted to pbf and tried. it shows the error "Error: Unimplemented type: 3" even used with "Content-Encoding", "gzip". How to displays the mbutils file in the map?

I'm using "leaflet-vector-tile-layer" package.

Comment: what software have you used to convert your MBTiles from OpenMapTiles? What kind of tiles did you download from OpenMapTiles, vector or raster ones?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `pbf` files extracted from .mbTiles.

The issue is those `pbf` files are in fact gzip archives. Consider "ungzipping" them before usage.